# How to generate inner loops automatically in Java

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to find a way to generate inner loops on demand (and have the depth as a variable).

In the following example, I am trying to generate a list of references such as **jobo.2.2.2.2.2.2** where each **.2** is added in the inner loop.

Here is what I have at the moment when I implement the new loop manually for 5 level of depth (**i, j, k, l**):

```
 public void buildTaskList(){
    String jobName ="jobo";
    String last="";
    long max=3;
    List<String> tasks = new ArrayList<>();


    for (long i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        for (long j = 1; j <= max; j++) {
            if (j==max){
                last="*";
                tasks.add(jobName+"."+i+"."+j+last);
            }else {
                last="";
                for (long k = 1; k <= max; k++) {
                    if (k==max){
                        last="*";
                        tasks.add(jobName+"."+i+"."+j+"."+k+last);
                    }else {
                        last="";
                        for (long l = 1; l <= max; l++) {
                            if (l==max){
                                last="*";
                                tasks.add(jobName+"."+i+"."+j+"."+k+"."+l+last);
                            }else{
                                last="";
                                for (long m = 1; m <= max; m++) {
                                    if (m==max){
                                        last="*";
                                        tasks.add(jobName+"."+i+"."+j+"."+k+"."+l+"."+m+last);
                                    }else{
                                        last="";
                                        for (long n = 1; n <= max; n++) {
                                            if (n==max)last="*";else last="";
                                            tasks.add(jobName+"."+i+"."+j+"."+k+"."+l+"."+m+"."+n+last);
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
    tasks.add(jobName+"."+(max+1)+last);
    System.out.println(tasks);
    }
```

The result here is:

```
jobo.1.1.1.1.1.1, jobo.1.1.1.1.1.2, jobo.1.1.1.1.1.3*, jobo.1.1.1.1.2.1, jobo.1.1.1.1.2.2, jobo.1.1.1.1.2.3*, jobo.1.1.1.1.3*, jobo.1.1.1.2.1.1, jobo.1.1.1.2.1.2, jobo.1.1.1.2.1.3*, jobo.1.1.1.2.2.1, jobo.1.1.1.2.2.2, jobo.1.1.1.2.2.3*, jobo.1.1.1.2.3*, jobo.1.1.1.3*, jobo.1.1.2.1.1.1, jobo.1.1.2.1.1.2, jobo.1.1.2.1.1.3*, jobo.1.1.2.1.2.1, jobo.1.1.2.1.2.2, jobo.1.1.2.1.2.3*, jobo.1.1.2.1.3*, jobo.1.1.2.2.1.1, jobo.1.1.2.2.1.2, jobo.1.1.2.2.1.3*, jobo.1.1.2.2.2.1, jobo.1.1.2.2.2.2, jobo.1.1.2.2.2.3*, jobo.1.1.2.2.3*, jobo.1.1.2.3*, jobo.1.1.3*, jobo.1.2.1.1.1.1, jobo.1.2.1.1.1.2, jobo.1.2.1.1.1.3*, jobo.1.2.1.1.2.1, jobo.1.2.1.1.2.2, jobo.1.2.1.1.2.3*, jobo.1.2.1.1.3*, jobo.1.2.1.2.1.1, jobo.1.2.1.2.1.2, jobo.1.2.1.2.1.3*, jobo.1.2.1.2.2.1, jobo.1.2.1.2.2.2, jobo.1.2.1.2.2.3*, jobo.1.2.1.2.3*, jobo.1.2.1.3*, jobo.1.2.2.1.1.1, jobo.1.2.2.1.1.2, jobo.1.2.2.1.1.3*, jobo.1.2.2.1.2.1, jobo.1.2.2.1.2.2, jobo.1.2.2.1.2.3*, jobo.1.2.2.1.3*, jobo.1.2.2.2.1.1, jobo.1.2.2.2.1.2, jobo.1.2.2.2.1.3*, jobo.1.2.2.2.2.1, jobo.1.2.2.2.2.2, jobo.1.2.2.2.2.3*, jobo.1.2.2.2.3*, jobo.1.2.2.3*, jobo.1.2.3*, jobo.1.3*, jobo.2.1.1.1.1.1, jobo.2.1.1.1.1.2, jobo.2.1.1.1.1.3*, jobo.2.1.1.1.2.1, jobo.2.1.1.1.2.2, jobo.2.1.1.1.2.3*, jobo.2.1.1.1.3*, jobo.2.1.1.2.1.1, jobo.2.1.1.2.1.2, jobo.2.1.1.2.1.3*, jobo.2.1.1.2.2.1, jobo.2.1.1.2.2.2, jobo.2.1.1.2.2.3*, jobo.2.1.1.2.3*, jobo.2.1.1.3*, jobo.2.1.2.1.1.1, jobo.2.1.2.1.1.2, jobo.2.1.2.1.1.3*, jobo.2.1.2.1.2.1, jobo.2.1.2.1.2.2, jobo.2.1.2.1.2.3*, jobo.2.1.2.1.3*, jobo.2.1.2.2.1.1, jobo.2.1.2.2.1.2, jobo.2.1.2.2.1.3*, jobo.2.1.2.2.2.1, jobo.2.1.2.2.2.2, jobo.2.1.2.2.2.3*, jobo.2.1.2.2.3*, jobo.2.1.2.3*, jobo.2.1.3*, jobo.2.2.1.1.1.1, jobo.2.2.1.1.1.2, jobo.2.2.1.1.1.3*, jobo.2.2.1.1.2.1, jobo.2.2.1.1.2.2, jobo.2.2.1.1.2.3*, jobo.2.2.1.1.3*, jobo.2.2.1.2.1.1, jobo.2.2.1.2.1.2, jobo.2.2.1.2.1.3*, jobo.2.2.1.2.2.1, jobo.2.2.1.2.2.2, jobo.2.2.1.2.2.3*, jobo.2.2.1.2.3*, jobo.2.2.1.3*, jobo.2.2.2.1.1.1, jobo.2.2.2.1.1.2, jobo.2.2.2.1.1.3*, jobo.2.2.2.1.2.1, jobo.2.2.2.1.2.2, jobo.2.2.2.1.2.3*, jobo.2.2.2.1.3*, jobo.2.2.2.2.1.1, jobo.2.2.2.2.1.2, jobo.2.2.2.2.1.3*, jobo.2.2.2.2.2.1, jobo.2.2.2.2.2.2, jobo.2.2.2.2.2.3*, jobo.2.2.2.2.3*, jobo.2.2.2.3*, jobo.2.2.3*, jobo.2.3*, jobo.3.1.1.1.1.1, jobo.3.1.1.1.1.2, jobo.3.1.1.1.1.3*, jobo.3.1.1.1.2.1, jobo.3.1.1.1.2.2, jobo.3.1.1.1.2.3*, jobo.3.1.1.1.3*, jobo.3.1.1.2.1.1, jobo.3.1.1.2.1.2, jobo.3.1.1.2.1.3*, jobo.3.1.1.2.2.1, jobo.3.1.1.2.2.2, jobo.3.1.1.2.2.3*, jobo.3.1.1.2.3*, jobo.3.1.1.3*, jobo.3.1.2.1.1.1, jobo.3.1.2.1.1.2, jobo.3.1.2.1.1.3*, jobo.3.1.2.1.2.1, jobo.3.1.2.1.2.2, jobo.3.1.2.1.2.3*, jobo.3.1.2.1.3*, jobo.3.1.2.2.1.1, jobo.3.1.2.2.1.2, jobo.3.1.2.2.1.3*, jobo.3.1.2.2.2.1, jobo.3.1.2.2.2.2, jobo.3.1.2.2.2.3*, jobo.3.1.2.2.3*, jobo.3.1.2.3*, jobo.3.1.3*, jobo.3.2.1.1.1.1, jobo.3.2.1.1.1.2, jobo.3.2.1.1.1.3*, jobo.3.2.1.1.2.1, jobo.3.2.1.1.2.2, jobo.3.2.1.1.2.3*, jobo.3.2.1.1.3*, jobo.3.2.1.2.1.1, jobo.3.2.1.2.1.2, jobo.3.2.1.2.1.3*, jobo.3.2.1.2.2.1, jobo.3.2.1.2.2.2, jobo.3.2.1.2.2.3*, jobo.3.2.1.2.3*, jobo.3.2.1.3*, jobo.3.2.2.1.1.1, jobo.3.2.2.1.1.2, jobo.3.2.2.1.1.3*, jobo.3.2.2.1.2.1, jobo.3.2.2.1.2.2, jobo.3.2.2.1.2.3*, jobo.3.2.2.1.3*, jobo.3.2.2.2.1.1, jobo.3.2.2.2.1.2, jobo.3.2.2.2.1.3*, jobo.3.2.2.2.2.1, jobo.3.2.2.2.2.2, jobo.3.2.2.2.2.3*, jobo.3.2.2.2.3*, jobo.3.2.2.3*, jobo.3.2.3*, jobo.3.3*, jobo.4*
```

Anyone knows how this can be simplified and controlled by a variable `int depth=123;` for example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Recursion (see wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

for example (draft, not checking)

```
@Test
public void buildTaskList1() {
    String jobName ="job";
    int depth=5;
    int max=3;
    List<String> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (long i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        buildTaskListRecursion(max, depth, tasks, jobName + "."+i);
    }
    tasks.add(jobName+"."+(max+1)+"*");
}


public void buildTaskListRecursion(int max,int depth, List<String> tasks, String jobName){
    String last="";
    for (long j = 1; j <= max; j++) {
        if (j==max){
            last="*";
            tasks.add(jobName+"."+j+last);
        }else {
            depth--;
            if(depth > 0) {
                buildTaskListRecursion(max, depth, tasks, jobName+"."+j);
            } else {
                tasks.add(jobName+"."+j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I disagree. Recursion might be unsafe and prone for stack overflow problems. This can be resolved with recursion, as you pointed out, but a better and more bullet-proof solution is to solve it iteratively. See my answer.

Comment: To be precise: avoid saying you **need**. Recursion is often easier to write down, but at least in real world scenarios, you absolutely strive to have a non-recursive solution.

Comment: @LajosArpad I believe this can be made tail recursive, which I believe is automatically optimized and won't have stackoverflow, because it can be unrolled..

Comment: @RandomnessSlayer you may achieve that in this specific case, but it's better to think about future readers of this, having issues which are not convertable into a tail recursive approach. So, while it is perfectly fine to suggest a simple-to-implement recursive approach, we should be **very** clear about its limitations and dangers.

Answer (score 2):

This option avoids recursion, and simply counts as you would when deciding the next element in the sequence:

```
private static class LevelGenerator implements Iterator<String> {
    private int[] current;  // min,min,min => min,min,min+1 => ... max,max,max
    private int min, max;   // at each position in current[] array
    private String next;    // to be returned when next() is called

    public LevelGenerator(int levels, int min, int max) {
        this.current = new int[levels];
        for (int i=0; i<levels; i++) this.current[i] = min;
        this.next = output();
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    /** 
     * Int array to string
     */
    private String output() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i : current) sb.append("." + i);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Updates current and next
     * counts as a human would: increments the last index that is not yet `max`,
     *    and then places all elements after it to `min`
     */
    private String step() {            
        for (int i=current.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            if (current[i] < max) { 
                current[i] ++;
                for (int j=i+1; j<current.length; j++) {
                    current[j] = min;
                }
                return output(); // next step is ready
            }
        }
        return null; // no next step
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        if (next == null) throw new IllegalStateException("iteration is finished");
        String output = next;
        next = step();
        return output;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return next != null;
    }
}

public static void main(String ... args) {
    LevelGenerator l = new LevelGenerator(3, 1, 4);
    while (l.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("job" + l.next());
    }
}
```

The output for this example would be:

```
job.1.1.1
job.1.1.2
job.1.1.3
job.1.1.4
job.1.2.1
job.1.2.2
job.1.2.3
job.1.2.4
job.1.3.1
job.1.3.2
job.1.3.3
job.1.3.4
job.1.4.1
job.1.4.2
job.1.4.3
job.1.4.4
job.2.1.1
...
job.4.4.4
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. The code that you provided  wouldn't return the under levels. Here it always remains with 3 dots when I need to have for example  job.4.4.4, then job.4.5*. (I probably should have simplified the example and/or described some more)However, the rest works as described, so I should be able to adapt it to my needs. Thx!

Comment: @Xbreizh Can you describe *when* those `*` need to be added? Whenever `max` is reached?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. To explain further, the output is a list of splitted tasks for which * defines the last element of the split. So, job.1 split in 2 is {job.1.1, job.1.2*}. if we split job.1.1 in 2, then we have {job.1.1.1, job.1.1.2*} ...

Comment: What goes after job.1.2*.1? Is it job.1.2*.2*? Are jobs always split in 2, or can they be split in 3? When do you know that you will need to split a job? My answer assumes that you want to generate all values from min...min to max...max, but if you want to selectively split tree-branches on demand it would look quite different...

Comment: Actually, I decided to split on fixed sizes here as the result of that function would be used in a test. But in the reality, the jobs can be split randomly in various parts with various levels of depth. I had no idea how to model it so I went with a list with stable max and depth. There is nothing possible after job.1.2* on that level of depth. It can't be split anymore. But then we would need job.2 then job.3, ...until we get the last piece (job.4* for example). But that job.2 can be split as job.2.1.1, job.2.1.2. job.2.1.3.1.1, job.2.1.3.1.2*, job.2.1.3* ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes

## 1. Support indexes

Create a stack of indexes of the size of depth.

## 2. Handle the levels properly

You need a currentDepth index to know where you were. This is 0 at first. Whenever an item is increased, push a new item to the stack with 0 as index. Whenever an item is going beyond max, pop it from the stack and increment the previous element. When the first element is popped, you completed all the work

## 3. You will need to logically know where you were.

## Alternatively you could generate code

But that's much more complicated.

EDIT

In agreement with Bdzzaid's legitimate request, I will briefly talk about the Composite Design Pattern. First, let's see a diagram from the page he shared with us:

[image]

Source: https://dzone.com/articles/composite-design-pattern-in-java-1

That's a good read I can wholeheartedly recommend to future readers. The idea is that we use the composition of very similar components in a tree-like manner. The pattern is applied on a stack in our case, which can be thought about as a tree having a single branch in all cases. The reason this is beneficial to think about in this way is that we might want to add support for multiple loops, maybe even in an assymmetryc manner at some point. Now, the components are the levels/indexes in our case and they, together form a composition of the stack (or, in more general terms, the tree).

This pattern can be reused in many different situations, so it is advisable to get familiar with it if you not already have.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. Let see if I am able to implement it now :)

Comment: @LajosArpad All you said is right, no reason for me to answer to this question. But, may I suggest you to complete your answer and talk about Composite Design Pattern ? The Composite Design Pattern is meant to "compose objects into a tree structure to represent part-whole hierarchies. Composite Pattern lets clients treat individual objects and compositions of objects uniformly" (see https://dzone.com/articles/composite-design-pattern-in-java-1)

Comment: @bdzzaid thanks for the suggestion, added a brief description to the answer.

Comment: There is no need for a stack (an array is easier to use), and the composite pattern is not especially useful either. I fail to see how this is an answer.

Comment: @tucuxi you can represent your stack in an array, increasing or decreasing your index would be your push/pop: https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/stack/array/ It appears to me that by stack you think about a class by that name, but when I speak about a stack, I mean anything that operates like a stack.

Comment: I am not writing that a stack / composition *cannot* be used, but I do not agree that it *should* be used. Can you simplify my answer (or any other) using either stacks or composition?

Comment: @tucuxi you still don't understand my point. The logic you have implemented is stack-like, minus the elegance and reusability. So you are not really proving a point.

Comment: Prove me wrong by showing more elegant and reusable code that uses stacks, and I will be happy to upvote you.

Comment: @tucuxi Your solution is stack-like. I don't know what's not clear about it, but I will not allocate more energy into discussing this with you.